# Click to slide second div not show properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

When i click one box then second box not come properly, show second box same as first box slide

http://jsfiddle.net/fgve2xuj/`
    
    Text

```
</div>
```

Text

```
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use callback . Jquery callback is fired once the animation is complete. This can be useful for stringing different animations together in sequence.

```
$( ".dihai" ).show( "drop", { direction: "right" }, "slow" );

$( ".dihai" ).click(function(){

    $( ".dihai" ).hide( "drop", { direction: "left" }, "slow" , function() { 
         $( ".dihai2" ).show( "drop", { direction: "right" }, "slow" ); 
    });

});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fgve2xuj/1/)

Comment: Ahaha just a second before I do! XD

Comment: @FahadHassan If this is the answer you was looking for, please accept it so other users may find it easily, thanks ;)